# Problem with the work of @njit in combining arrays

Tags: python, numba

A simple example of combining numba arrays shows that the union does not work with `@njit` and gives errors.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])
arr3 = np.array([7, 8, 9])
print('arr1 :', arr1)
print()
print('arr2 :', arr2)
print()
print('arr3 :', arr3)
```

without @njit

```
def union_of_arrays():
    
    arr = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3]).T
    
    return arr

arr = union_of_arrays()
print(arr)
```

Everything works, now with @njit

```
@njit
def union_of_arrays():
    
    arr = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3]).T
    
    return arr

arr = union_of_arrays()
print(arr)
```

throws an error:

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 8
      4     arr = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3]).T
      6     return arr
----> 8 arr = union_of_arrays()
      9 print(arr)

File c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args..error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function() found for signature:
 
...


File "..\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8316\2415862080.py", line 4:
```

How to fix the error so that the code would work?

The code is the same, but it doesn't work with `@njit`.

Comment: I think numba doesn't support references to global arrays, only global constants. If you pass them in as parameters, does it work?

Comment: AFAIK, global refarences works but they are considered as constants (so immutable theoretically). This is generally a bad idea to do that with arrays. In fact, this is a bad software engineering practice in nearly all languages including Python.

Answer (score 3):

You can create empty array inside numba function and then assign the arrays using indexing. Then transpose:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit


arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3], dtype=float)
arr2 = np.array([4, 5, 6], dtype=float)
arr3 = np.array([7, 8, 9], dtype=float)
print('arr1:', arr1)
print()
print('arr2:', arr2)
print()
print('arr3:', arr3)


@njit
def union_of_arrays(arr1, arr2, arr3):
    arr = np.empty((3, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    arr[0, :] = arr1
    arr[1, :] = arr2
    arr[2, :] = arr3
    return arr.transpose()

arr = union_of_arrays(arr1, arr2, arr3)
print(arr)
```

Prints:

```
arr1: [1. 2. 3.]

arr2: [4. 5. 6.]

arr3: [7. 8. 9.]
[[1. 4. 7.]
 [2. 5. 8.]
 [3. 6. 9.]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! At this point, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

`njit` doesn't support creation of a NumPy array via a list of NumPy arrays. You need to instead create an empty array using `np.empty((3, 3), np.float64)` and then assign values by indexing.

Comment: Thank you very much! At this point, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You dont actually need the decorator to make this code work and just by simply write this code :

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
arr2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])
arr3 = np.array([7, 8, 9])
print('arr1:', arr1)
print()
print('arr2:', arr2)
print()
print('arr3:', arr3)


def union_of_arrays(arr1, arr2, arr3):
  arr = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3]).T
  return arr


arr = union_of_arrays(arr1, arr2, arr3)
print(arr)
```

It doesn't give me any errors

Comment: The outcome was as follows: TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 15
     12     arr = np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3]).T 
     13     return arr
---> 15 arr = union_of_arrays(arr1, arr2, arr3) 
     16 print(arr)

File c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "

Comment: 465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args..error_rewrite(e, issue_type)

Comment: 407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function() found for signature:
 
...


File "..\..\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8316\479048469.py", line 12:

Comment: It didn't fit in one comment

Comment: Have you installed njit and numpy on your pip

Comment: Yes, I installed everything

Comment: I modified my answer again tell me if it works

Comment: Since it works for me with my python interpreter

Comment: But it is necessary that it would work with @njit. That's the problem.